# Count of bindings gor a notification service in twlio

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I am tryng to find the number of bindings for a notification service in twilio

Bindings are created for subscribers by using the following

```
notify.bindings.create(identity:this.fromNumber),bindingType: 'sms',address: this.fromNumber)
```

I am trying to find out how many people have subscribed

I tried using notify.bindings.length but that seems to always return 1 as the value

I cannot find any documentation that describes the methods available for the notify object

Answer (score 0):

Look at the code example, [Read Multiple Binding Resources](https://www.twilio.com/docs/notify/api/binding-resource?code-sample=code-read-multiple-binding-resources&code-language=Node.js&code-sdk-version=3.x#read-multiple-binding-resources)